# MongoDB Auto-Incrementing id field with java mongo driver?

Tags: java, dao, mongodb-java, morphia

Whole day I have tried to find a answer on the question:

*"How to add auto-Incrementing "id" field in an Entity class?"*.

I am using Morphia (a type-safe java library for Mongo DB). After a couple hours of digging in source code and googling I have found a [LongIdEntity](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/utils/LongIdEntity.java) class in [org.mongodb.morphia.utils](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/tree/master/morphia/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/utils) package. Based on this class I have implemented the following solution. See below:

**City class:**

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

**Hotel class:**

```
@Entity
public class Hotel {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

**CityLongIdEntity class:**

```
public class CityLongIdEntity extends LongIdEntity {

    public CityLongIdEntity(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds);
    }

}
```

**HotelLongIdEntity class:**

```
public class HotelLongIdEntity extends LongIdEntity {

    public HotelLongIdEntity(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds);
    }

}
```

**DAO implementation:**

**CityDAO class:**

```
public class CityDAO extends BasicDAO<City, Long> {

    public CityDAO(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds);
    }

    @Override
    public Key<City> save(City c) {

        if (c.getId() == null) {

            CityLongIdEntity ent = new CityLongIdEntity(getDs());
            getDs().save(ent);
            c.setId(ent.getMyLongId());
        }
        return getDs().save(c);
    }
}
```

**HotelDAO class:**

```
public class HotelDAO extends BasicDAO<Hotel, Long> {

    public HotelDAO(Datastore ds) {
        super(ds);
    }

    @Override
    public Key<Hotel> save(Hotel h) {

        if (h.getId() == null) {

            HotelLongIdEntity ent = new HotelLongIdEntity(getDs());
            getDs().save(ent);
            h.setId(ent.getMyLongId());
        }
        return getDs().save(h);
    }
}
```

Or you can see all this code on the [Github](https://github.com/jfenuk/mongodb-morphia-LongIdEntity)

The UML diagram is also available: [image]

All this code works as expected and I am happy, but I have a couple questions:

- As you can see, for each Entity I need to create additional Entity, for example: for entity `City` I created `CityLongIdEntity` (this entity is crucial part of auto-incrementing functionality) . In this case, if my app will have 20 Entities (`City`, `Address`, `Hotel`, `User`, `Room`, `Order` etc.) I will need to create a 40 classes! I am afraid, but I think it will be "Code smell". *Am I right*?
- Also, the `Entity` doesn't know about `EntityNameLongIdEntity` and `EntityNameLongIdEntity` has no idea who is `Entity`. And only specific `EntityDAO` class combines ans uses those classes together. Is it ok? *Or it is again code smell*?
- Each `EntityDAO` class overrides extends `BasicDAO` class and overrides method `save()`. The difference between overrided methods `save()` for different `DAO` classes is minimal. I am afraid. that is code duplication and code smell again. *Am I right*?

please provide your opinion.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need id's of type `Long` only?  Generally in MongoDB, you use the `ObjectId` type for id's which can be generated on the client side or server side (implicitly)

Comment: +1 Alex, also each save with incremented id leads to additional findAndModify call. By the way, Morphia is good, but not flexible et al, I've switched to Jackson/MongoJack after several years of Morphia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We require numeric IDs on some entities, but our implementation is a little different:

1. We use a regular ObjectId on all entities. Where required, we add a numeric ID.
2. There is a dedicated [AutoIncrementEntity](https://github.com/xeraa/morphia-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/net/xeraa/morphia_demo/entities/AutoIncrementEntity.java), which keeps a counter for different keys — that would be your class name.
3. We don't use DAOs but a generic save method, where we check if we have an instance of a class with a numeric ID. If that ID hasn't been set, we fetch one and update the AutoIncrementEntity. The [relevant method](https://github.com/xeraa/morphia-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/net/xeraa/morphia_demo/persistence/MongodbGenericPersistence.java#L45) isn't used at the moment — let me know if it's totally unclear and I'll finish that code.

Two more things from my implementation, which might be a little confusing:

- You can always provide a starting number, so our numeric IDs could be 1000, 1001, 1002,... instead of 1, 2, 3,...
- The key in the AutoIncrementEntity isn't required to be a class, it could also be a subset. For example, you want to number employees within a company, then the key for employees of company A would be `employee-A`, for company B `company-B`,...